# Next Js Google Auth with Strapi CMS

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-oauth, strapi, next-auth

I am trying to do authentication using google in my next js and strapi app.

However, I keep getting the error below:

`Error: This action with HTTP GET is not supported by NextAuth.js`.

This is the code from 'api/auth/[...nextauth].jsx'

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const options = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process?.env?.NEXT_PUBLIC_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.jwt = token.jwt;
      session.id = token.id;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (user) {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account.access_token}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        token.jwt = data.jwt;
        token.id = data.user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
};

const Auth = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options);

export default Auth;
```

I have set the redirect URIs in the google console to be :

```
https://frontend.com/api/auth/callback/google
```

```
https://backend.com/api/auth/callback/google
```

Also, I have set the redirect URI in strapi to be :

```
https://frontend.com/api/auth/callback/google
```

Comment: What endpoint are you accessing when you get the HTTP GET error?

Comment: https://backend.com/connect/google, I am not sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: @Lenzman No, not yet.

Comment: @ThinkDigital Try the following answer I posted. let me know if it is not working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there was something I didn't like about the auth flow
initially but didn't know how to work around it either.

It's the fact that next auth had to come into play. For what?
I didn't like it either explained for the right reasons or not.

Then, I worked around a miracle.

I created a new file `[provider].js` inside `/pages/auth`.

*Notice its not inside the `/pages/api/auth`*

```
    import React from "react";
    
    import { api } from "../../services/api";
    
    export async function getServerSideProps({
      params: { provider },
      query: { access_token },
      ...ctx
    }) {
      const res = await api(
        `/auth/${provider}/callback?access_token=${access_token}`,
        "GET"
      );
      if (res?.jwt) {
         //do something
      }
    
      return {
        props: { },
      };
    }
    
    const Connect = () => {
   
      return (
        <div>
          Redirecting...
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Connect;
```

The redirect URL to my front-end app:

```
http://localhost:3000/auth/google
```

In Google console: Under Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs:

Authorized redirect URIs:

```
http://localhost:1337/connect/google/callback
http://localhost:3000/auth/callback/google
```

**And I got this working fine even in production.**

Comment: Do you know if we can send more data other than access_token to strapi?

Comment: @Lenzman, I am not sure about that 100%, however, I think you should first justify the thought of sending more data to strapi other than the access_token. I say that because the data sent to strapi, for example, the access_token serves a purpose that is 'authenticating' in short. So if we are to justify why we need something other than access_token then maybe just maybe we might see a workaround to your question. I know you are not fully answered and I hope this reply gets you somewhere to start at

Comment: I am trying to send the first name and last name from the front-end form with access_token because discord doesn't have that and I need the users to enter it themselves, So I have added those fields to the user is strapi and saving them. I am new with strapi. Do you think there is another better way to do that?

Comment: Hi, so sorry for the late replies I have not had much time to hang around : ). Anyways if I understood your question correctly this [forum](https://forum.strapi.io/t/profile-image-with-google-auth-provider/5504/4) touches on ideas of how we could work around this problem. Pay special attention to the solution ( out of context of the google image issue/thread on the forum to what you're asking though) posted by Gwenole_Midy. The [providers.js] file mentioned can be manipulated in different ways just by looking at it. If this makes sense try it out and give me feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to configure Strapi with Google provider as authenticator and integrated it with the NextJS project using NextAuth as follows.

- **Strapi v3.6.8** running in **localhost:1337**
- **Frontend** **NextProject -v 12.2.3** running on **localhost:3000**
- **"next-auth": "^4.10.3"** installed in NextJS project

**In my Strapi Google provider configuration:**

The redirect URL to your front-end app:

- http://localhost:3000/api/auth/google

**In Google console:** Under Credentials -> OAuth 2.0 Client IDs:

Authorized redirect URIs:

- http://localhost:1337/connect/google/callback
- http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google

**[...nextauth].ts** -     /pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
 
export default NextAuth({

    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],

    session: { strategy: "jwt" },

    callbacks: {
        
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.jwt = token.jwt;
            session.id = token.id;
            return session;
        },

        async jwt({ token, user, account }) {

            const isSignIn = user ? true : false;
            if (isSignIn) {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/auth/${account?.provider}/callback?access_token=${account?.access_token}`
                );
                const data = await response.json();
                token.jwt = data.jwt;
                token.id = data.user.id;
            }
            return token
        }
    }

});
```

On your page use the following function from Next to signing.

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
signIn();
```

---

**Update:**

For ***Strapi 4.3.0*** **I had to change the URL in JWT callback from**
`http://localhost:1337/auth/google/callback?access_token={accessToken}`

to

`http://localhost:1337/api/auth/google/callback?access_token={accessToken}`

Comment: Thanks but I totally made a different approach. I will share it as a post.

Comment: ok great, please share that as well